# How to access material ui Expanded property in Expansion Panel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

As shown in the picture below:

[image: The property to be accessed]

I needed to make the expansion panel (only the expansion part, when the expansion was active) occupy 100% of the Div it is currently occupying. That `height: 100%` does the job, but inside my styling, I can't access that property correctly.

My expansion panel code snippet:

```
<ExpansionPanel classes={{ root: classes.expanded }}
```

My styling:

```
expanded: {
  '&$expanded': {
    height: '100%'
  },
  margin: '0 !important',
  boxShadow: 'none',
  borderRadius: 0,
  '&::before': {
    content: 'none'
  }
}
```

But when rendering my styling it results in the following picture:

[image]

It does not apply the styling to the `.MuiExpansionPanel-root.Mui-expanded`, instead, it is increasing the size of the box when it is not expanded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

see the [MatUI api docs](https://mui.com/api/accordion/) under the css section and the rule names. those are the keys you need to provide to the classes prop. You are setting your expanded class name to the `root`, you need to set it to `expanded`

EDIT based on code sandbox

this

```
  expandedPanel: {
     "&$expanded": {
        height: "100%"
     }
  }
```

is equivalent to the css

```
.expandedPanel.expanded{}
```

However, MatUI is conditionally applying the expandedPanel class already and there is not yet another .expanded class which is why it fails. you dont need to do the &$expanded check yourself. Just need to change it to

```
  expandedPanel: {
      height: "100%"
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already tried setting the property to expanded `<ExpansionPanel classes={{ root: classes.expanded, expanded: classes.expansionPanel }}` and created a new styling but it does not work.

Comment: create a simple example in codesandbox and link it in your original post so we can run it

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/expansion-panel-demo-forked-llp13?file=/demo.js

here you go.

Comment: updated in the answer so I could use code blocks

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now understood my mistake. thanks for the help @Bastiat